# PageSpeed Insights complains about Expect-CT header for my website but we don't output that header

Tags: http-headers, response-headers, pagespeed-insights

Google Tool says `The 'Expect-CT' header is deprecated and will be removed. Chrome requires Certificate Transparency for all publicly trusted certificates issued after April 30, 2018.`

However, when I load the URL and use the Chrome filter: `has-response-header:expect-ct` nothing comes up.

Any hint?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. In dev tool network tab, select one of your downloaded images and you will likely see the header present there.